# how to change brightness of series using states in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How can I change brightness of series when I hover the series using states like here I am changing color but I want to change brightness of color.

```
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: 'green'
            },
            select: {
                color: 'blue'
            }
        }   
      }
```

any help is highly appreciated...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by brightness?  Do you want do you just want a brighter shade of color?  Or do you want to adjust the alpha channel?

Comment: I want little bit brighter version.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color on the select state as you did but you have to add the select state yourself using :

```
this.setState(this.state === 'select' ? '' : 'select');
```

for example in a **click** event.

as said in this question :
[Highchart - set a line style ( width, color...) on selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252703/highchart-set-a-line-style-width-color-on-selection)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify any colour you want, using standard css color definitions, e.g. '#00FF00' or 'rgb(0,200,0)'.

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    states: {
        hover: {
            color: '#00FF00'
        },
        select: {
            color: '#0000FF'
        }
    }   
  }
```