# Highchart - set a line style ( width, color...) on selection

Tags: highcharts

using Highchart I'd like to select series by clicking on it and change its width on selection ( so we can see it is selected)

the thing is, the selection seems to work (it toggles the selected value displayed in console) but I can't figure out how I can set a lineWidth from the click event :

the example is working to select series :

```
line: {
    events: {
        click: function(event) {

            this.select();
                        console.log( this.name+", selected : "+ this.selected);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I can also show / hide series,  but how can I change the lineWidth ?
I managed to display the tooltip only for selected series, but I need those series to be more visible than the others.

I've tried to add a select state on the series as it works on markers but it doesn't seem to work for lines :

```
                series: {
                    states: {
                            select: {

                                lineWidth: 10
                            }
                    },
                             ...
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setState` instead.

```
this.setState(this.state === 'select' ? '' : 'select');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G9d9H/3/)

Comment: it should fit my needs thanks.  but it won't set the series as selected, I also use it with the checkbox in legend. I guess I'll have to change the select state in the selection event from this checkbox ?

Comment: There is still a problem, we can see it in the demo you attached : the select state shouldn't change on mouse move, when other series got the hover state...  see what i meen?

Comment: I guess its because when moving my mouse away from the line, the sate change to remove the hover state... but it shouldnt remove also the selected state...  any way to disable the hover mecanism ? I don't really need it.

Comment: I accept this answer as it fit the first need, but I'll create a new question about this hover event overriding the select state.